# Read XML element from XML Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `XML column` in a table with values like

```
<m lingua="1">  
  <coloriVini>  
    <i n="8" />  
    <i n="2" />  
    <i n="3" />  
    <i n="4" />  
    <i n="5" />  
    <i n="6" />  
    <i n="7" />  
  </coloriVini>  
</m>
```

and I need to make a join with values from `/m/coloriVini/i/@n` with another table
with will be displayed comma separated , but this I can handle

One idea is to make a variable and store the XML, but I am asking you if I can do it easily

I've tried

```
SELECT [L].[nome]
, p.value('./coloriVini', 'xml')
FROM [dbo].[contatto] C
CROSS APPLY [xmlMailing].nodes('m') t(p)
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[lingua] L ON p.value('./@lingua', 'int') = L.id
```

I know `p.value('./coloriVini', 'xml')` or `p.value('./coloriVini', 'nvarchar(200)')` doesn't work, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = 
'<m lingua="1">  
  <coloriVini>  
    <i n="8" />  
    <i n="2" />  
    <i n="3" />  
    <i n="4" />  
    <i n="5" />  
    <i n="6" />  
    <i n="7" />  
  </coloriVini>  
</m>'

DECLARE @lingua TABLE
(
      id INT
    , nome CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @lingua (id, nome)
VALUES 
    (8, '8'),
    (2, '2')

SELECT 
      l.nome
    , x.coloriVini
FROM (
    SELECT 
          id = t.p.value('@n', 'int') 
        , coloriVini = t.p.query('../.')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/m/coloriVini/i') t(p)
) x
JOIN @lingua l ON l.id = x.id
```